# Как произвести коррекцию времени в Windows через командную строку

Tags: windows, cmd, время, командная-строка

На простых электронных часах "Электроника", всегда был режим коррекции времени, т.е. часы умели каждый день корректировать время на нужное число миллисекунд (вперёд или назад).

Даже в самых современных версиях ОС Windows, отчего-то такой опции нет и всё завязано на синхронизации времени через сервера Майкрософт при условии наличии доступа в интернет. Доступа в интернет компьютер не имеет, но есть цель автоматически корректировать время после каждого включения ПК на нужное количество секунд (например 2 секунды). Как бы это реализовать.

Готового решения или утилиты не нашёл, хотя допускаю, что мог плохо искать. Посредством команды echo %time% можно получить текущее время, а как его модифицировать и сохранить понятие не имею. Есть какие-то светлые идеи?
Есть идеи?

Comment: Лучше на VBScript получить текущее время, добавить нужное смещение, сформировать и выполнить `time {новое значение}`. Потому как прибавлять время в CMD - сущее мучение. Да, и учти - на изменение системного времени надо иметь соотв. права.

Comment: только учти, что в компьютере работают 2 таймера - тот который в BIOS (с точностью до секунды) и тот, который в винде (с долями секунды).  при загрузке винды первый используется для инициализации второго.  а дальше каждый таймер работает со своей скоростью (один может спешить, а другой - отставать).  time вроде бы устанавливает их оба сразу.